# Where are sails.helpers functions coming from in the default sails web app

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am curious as to where sails.helpers.x.y() functions are coming from in the example web app that comes with sails.

After running `sails new test-project`, selecting the web app and looking around a bit I noticed that many files are calling functions like `sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword()`.

However when looking in the `helpers` folder, the only file there is `send-template-email` with nothing resembling a function to hash passwords.

I've read the docs on sails helper function [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers) and it doesn't mention any default helper functions like hashPassword.  I have also gone through the debugger in vscode and found that `sails.helpers.passwords.hashpassword()` is indeed defined, but I can't find it anywhere when I search through the source.

Does anybody know where these helpers are coming from?

For reference the part of the code that I debugged to get to the `hashPassword()` call was in `signup.js` here:

```
var newUserRecord = await User.create(_.extend({
      emailAddress: newEmailAddress,
      password: await sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword(inputs.password),
      fullName: inputs.fullName,
      tosAcceptedByIp: this.req.ip
    }, sails.config.custom.verifyEmailAddresses? {
      emailProofToken: await sails.helpers.strings.random('url-friendly'),
      emailProofTokenExpiresAt: Date.now() + sails.config.custom.emailProofTokenTTL,
      emailStatus: 'unconfirmed'
    }:{}))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They come from the sails-hook-organics package, check here the password methods, https://github.com/sailshq/sails-hook-organics/blob/a27db6c93e7333f5036a54ceb13a2e3b3fa0ae26/OTHER-USEFUL-METHODS.md